# Refactor @FirestoreQuery to class outside View

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `@FirestoreQuery` in my View like so:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "cars", predicates: [
        .where(field: "owners", arrayContains: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
    ])
    private var cars: [Car]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(cars) { car in
                Text(car)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want to use the same query in another view, so to avoid double reads and code duplication I want to move it to another class `CarsProvider`. I have tried the following:

```swift
class CarsProvider: ObservableObject {
    @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "cars", predicates: [
        .where(field: "owners", arrayContains: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
    ])
    var cars: [Car]
    
}

struct TestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var carsProvider: CarsProvider
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(carsProvider.cars) { car in
                Text(car)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when running it on a device I get an error: `Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.`

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You have to use snapshot listener. The property wrapper only works in a view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76569481/how-to-use-swifts-asyncthrowingstream-with-firestore-listeners/76573528#76573528

Answer (score 0):

I went with the recommendation of @lorem-ipsum :

```swift
@MainActor
class CarProvider: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var cars = [Car]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
    
    func subscribe(uid: String) {
        listenerRegistration?.remove()
        
        listenerRegistration = db.collection("cars")
            .whereField("owners", arrayContains: uid)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No documents")
                    return
                }
                self.cars = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                    return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Car.self)
                }
            }
    }
}
```